# How to get access token using refresh token?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

In my app we want to provide login with google. So i went throught the folowing [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java) and created a sample extending it by setting access_type to offline. So that i can get refresh token as their will be background task that will perform operation on those account after a particular interval of time, example: saving starrred mail in some file on server for each user.

So i need to know:

1. How to save refresh token ? like save it in DB with userId or somthing or save whole credential object as few post i have seen use credential object
2. How to use refresh token to get accesstoken ?
3. When does refresh token expires?

Code reference will be very useful.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

1.You can save the refresh token in DB as like userId, you can get new  access token by using the refresh token

2.You need to pass the Client Id, Client Secret and Refresh token to get the new access token

3.Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access.

Comment: Can you please post an example or an example of the URL that need to be created for the same ?

Comment: Which is better? Saving the refreshToken or the whole credential object? Also how actually does google refreshes the access token? Is it while making the credential object (if yes then you cannot store the cred obj anywhere) or is it while loading the session from the credential obj?